# The Hamiltonian cycle in a Cayley graph whose corresponding group has a finite cyclic normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, cayley-graphs, hamiltonicity

Let $S$ generate a finite group $G$ and $s \in S$ such that $\langle s\rangle \trianglelefteq G$, ${\rm Cay}(G/\langle s\rangle,S)$ has a Hamiltonian cycle.

Let $(s_1,s_2, \cdots, s_n)$ be the Hamiltonian cycle in ${\rm Cay}(G/\langle s\rangle,S)$ and $k=|s_1 s_2 \cdots s_n|$.

Let $m=|G|/(nk)$

Claim: $(s^{m-1}, s_1, s^{m-1}, s_2, s^{m-1}, \cdots, s^{m-1}, s_n)^k$ is a Hamiltonian cycle in ${\rm Cay}(G,S)$.

In the above, how can I understand regarding the hamiltonian cycle expressed by the claim and the value $m$?

Like, can I think like, if $|G|$ can be a value like $pq$, and $|s|=q$, and then $|k|=q$, and $m=pq/q q$? What type of values will be occupied by $m$ and will it be traversing the vertices belonging to cosets of $\langle s\rangle$, when we take $s^{m-1}$?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Even putting this aside, I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: Thank you @verret I found it in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.5795.pdf under the second point in  the proof of Lemma 2.27 in page 11. I was also feeling dubious that $m$ might not be an integer. But I think it has to be. In my question I need to get a clear idea about $m$ so that I can understand what vertices will be traversed when they say $s^{m-1}$.